# Java: convert java.awt.Color to javafx.scene.paint.Color

Tags: java, javafx, awt

How can I conver one to another? I thought a way via rgb string, but this case alpha layer is ignored. So the question - how to convert one to another with alpha?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Get each component from the awt Color object and use the `javafx.scene.paint.Color.rgb(...)` static method. Note that the awt Color has a `getAlpha()` method that returns the alpha as an `int` in the range `0-255`, whereas `javafx.scene.paint.Color.rgb(...)` expects the alpha value as a `double` in the range `0.0-1.0`:

```
java.awt.Color awtColor = ... ;
int r = awtColor.getRed();
int g = awtColor.getGreen();
int b = awtColor.getBlue();
int a = awtColor.getAlpha();
double opacity = a / 255.0 ;
javafx.scene.paint.Color fxColor = javafx.scene.paint.Color.rgb(r, g, b, opacity);
```